# count number of rows in a dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, dataframe

I have some issues in a code where i want to fill a dataframe, depending on another one.
To explain, in a dataframe I have replacements of components classified with codes to know their specific emplacements. I want to be able to count how many replacement I have and put this number in another dataframe.
this part of my code looks like that:

```
import plotly.express as px

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

#import excel from database

d=pd.read_excel("replacements.xlsx")
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

#we create 3 dataframe to put respectively number of replacements, percentages and failures rates.Here, we focus on the number of replacements, because it will be another process to fill the others.

```
tab_nb_replacements=pd.DataFrame(columns=['electrical auxiliary power supply','process monitoring','wind turbine system','generator system','transmission of electrical energy','structures connected to production','auxiliary systems'], index=['falaise_nb_replacements',...,'quittebeuf_nb_replacements])
```

As you can see, only some ligns are presented. Below, i fill with zero all the index 'falaise_nb_replacements' with 0 (I did it also for all indexes).

```
tab_nb_replacements['electrical auxiliary power supply']['falaise_nb_replacements']=0
tab_nb_replacements['process monitoring']['falaise_nb_replacements']=0
tab_nb_replacements['wind turbine system']['falaise_nb_replacements']=0
tab_nb_replacements['generator system']['falaise_nb_replacements']=0
tab_nb_replacements['transmission of electrical energy']['falaise_nb_replacements']=0
tab_nb_replacements['structures connected to production']['falaise_nb_replacements']=0
tab_nb_replacements['auxiliary systems']['falaise_nb_replacements']=0
```

########### I tried different ways to obtain the number of replacements ######

**##NOTE: for the site falaise, we want to select a lign when the value in the column 'RDSPP code' starts with 'B' and when the value in the column 'WTName' is 'Falaise'.**

##first method

```
tab_nb_replacements['electrical auxiliary power supply']['falaise_nb_replacements']=np.where(((df['RDSPP code'].str[:1]=='B') & (df['WTName']=='Falaise')),tab_nb_replacements['electrical auxiliary power supply']['falaise_nb_replacements']+1,tab_nb_replacements['electrical auxiliary power supply']['falaise_nb_replacements'])
```

#second method

```
df.loc[(df['RDSPP code'].str[:1]=='B') and (df['WTName']=='Falaise'),tab_nb_replacements['electrical auxiliary power supply']['falaise_nb_replacements']] = tab_nb_replacements['electrical auxiliary power supply']['falaise_nb_replacements']+1
```

#third method

```
tab_nb_replacements['electrical auxiliary power supply']['falaise_nb_replacements']=(df[df['RDSPP code'].str[:1]=='B' and df['WTName']=='Falaise']).count()
```

#### Any of these methods gave me results. Indeed with these methods, I obtain:

```
"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
```

If anybody has a solution or some advices on it, it will be really helpful!

Bests,

Answer (score 0):

For third method you mentioned `df['WTName']=='Falaise'` will give error, because `df['WTName']`'s data type is `pandas.series` and you can't compare it with `string`. So you must cast it to string like below:

```
df['WTName'].astype(str) == 'Falaise'
```

Comment: Hi, I tried as you sugested for the third method which gave me:                          tab_nb_replacements['electrical auxiliary power supply']['falaise_nb_replacements']=(df[df['RDSPP code'].str[:1]=='B' and df['WTName'].astype(str)=='Falaise']).count()                      but I still obtain ' ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Finally I obtain good results by using:  dff=df.copy()
mask=(dff['Site'].astype(str)=='Falaise') & (dff['RDSPP code'].str[:1]=='B')
dff=dff[mask]
tab_nb_replacements['electrical auxiliary power supply']['falaise_nb_replacements']=len(dff)

Comment: I did for all of them manually (copy-past) and I have good results. But i didn't succeed to do it with a loop, for exemple create a list with all name column of the dataframe and fill the result like below:     for x in (LIST_name_column)                                      dff=df.copy()
mask=(dff['Site'].astype(str)=='Falaise') & (dff['RDSPP code'].str[:1]=='B')
dff=dff[mask]
tab_nb_replacements[x]['falaise_nb_replacements']=len(dff)                                                                        This method doesn't work, do you have an idea how to do it properly and automatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand it that way.